# Game of Life with random lattice and first iterations

Tags: cellular-automata

I would like to generate a random 100 x 100 Lattice, plot this and then, say, the first 3 iterations of Conway's Game of Life.

How can I do this with Mathematica?

I only came up with:

```
gameOfLife = {224, {2, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}, {1, 1}};
board = RandomInteger[1, {100, 100}];
ArrayPlot[board]
ArrayPlot[Last[ CellularAutomaton[gameOfLife, board, {{0, 1}}]] ]
```

Does this show the first iteration?

Comment: Why `RandomInteger` and not for instance `ConstantArray`? Speed-wise there's not much of a difference, and both generate packed arrays (contrary to `Table` which is 5 times faster), but I can imagine that 'random' may be confusing to the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the 10 first iteration for a simple starting configuration: `board`:

```
board = ConstantArray[0, {100, 100}]; board[[50 ;; 52, 50 ;; 53]] = 1;
ArrayPlot /@ CellularAutomaton["GameOfLife", board, 10]
```

[image]

Comment: I do njot understand what board = RandomInteger[0, {100, 100}]; board[[50 ;; 52, 50 ;; 53]] = 1; is doing.

Comment: It simply sets up a board 100x100 with all zeros (aka dead cells) and some pixels in the center (aka life cells) to one.

Comment: Sorry I was simply too lazy and took your code and changed it in the simplest way possible. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Now, I get what you did, thanks. But why not starting with a random table consisting of zeros and ones? I want to start with a random setup.

Comment: That's o.k., but I wanted to see the if the evolution works o.k. and that can be easier done with a simple pattern.

Comment: How can I plot only the n-th iteration, say the third one?

Comment: E.g.:  `ArrayPlot @ CellularAutomaton["GameOfLife", board, 3][[3]]`